# Rspec: testing nested controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, controller, rspec

I have a nested controller that works fine, and I'd like to setup rspec to also test a nested controlled, but it doesn't test the controller unless I specify it.

i.e. my rspec test controller is here:
/spec/controllers/organizations/memberships_controller.rb

but when I run rspec to test everything, it tests everything except the nested controller:

```
bundle exec rspec spec
```

to test the nested controlled, I have to specifically ask rspec to test it:

```
bundle exec rspec spec/controllers/organizations/memberships_controller.rb
```

Is there anyway to make rspec test the nested controlled automatically?

Thanks.

Sean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not picking it up because it doesn't end in **_spec.rb**

Rename it to spec/controllers/organizations/memberships_controller_spec.rb